# Make multiple tables display in one line with scroll

Tags: html, css

So I am creating tables on a page dynamically, and the rows in each table are also dynamic. I want to display them all in one line and make them scroll horizontally if there is an overflow instead of wrapping. I set inline and overflow scroll:

```
.tableDiv {width:100%; overflow:scroll; display:inline}
```

but they are still wrapping. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xAxfr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xAxfr/2/

```
.tableDiv {
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

`white-space:nowrap;` and `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left` on `.table` and add `white-space: nowrap` on `.tableDiv`.

http://jsfiddle.net/xAxfr/1/

Comment: It looks like that is just stacking them, I want them all in the same line next to each other and to scroll horizontally, not vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use "The Table Method" as described [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/).  If you next the tables in another table instead of a div, you can make the row as wide as you want creating the same effect.

ex.

```
<table class="tableContainer">
   <tr> 
    <td>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                Table One
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                two
            </td>
            <td>
                three
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                four
            </td>
            <td>
                five
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                Table Two
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                two
            </td>
            <td>
                three
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                four
            </td>
            <td>
                five
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
```